# Question about this.from."operation"

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have this form :

```
<form action="index.php?explore=browse" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="artist" value="<?=$artist?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="event" value="<?=$event?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="date" value="<?=$date?>" />

    <a onclick="this.form.artist.value=all; this.form.submit();return false" href="#">All</a>
</form>
```

and I'd like to know :

1. Why it doenst put the value "all" to the artist field?
2. Is this Javascript? Or easy HTML?
3. Is better translate this with jQuery/JS Handler or this is better? (light, crossbrowsers..and so on)

Hope you can help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the
`this.form.artist.value=all;`
to
`this.parentNode.artist.value='all';`

The way you use it makes two wrong assumptions

1. it assumes that links inside a form have a form attribute.. They do not. Only input elements have a form attribute. Using `parentNode` should do the trick for you particular case since the link is a direct child of the form element.
2. it expects a variable with name all exists and it tries to put the content of that variable in the input. 
   Making **all** be a string by wrapping it to single quotes `'` should do what you want.

**demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/vzuFD/

---

With jQuery you could do

```
<form action="index.php?explore=browse" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="artist" value="<?=$artist?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="event" value="<?=$event?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="date" value="<?=$date?>" />

    <a id="all" href="#">All</a>
</form>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $('#all').click(function(){
        $(this)
            .closest('form')
            .find(':input[name=artist]')
            .val('all')
            .end()
            .submit();
    });
  });
</script>
```

**demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/vzuFD/1/

Answer (score 2):

- If you want to use this JavaScript line then change your code with: `this.form.artist.value="all"`
- Yes it is HTML with simple inline JavaScript.
- You can use JQuery also by following changing :

First change your HTML Code with the following:

```
<form action="index.php?explore=browse" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="artist" name="artist" value="<?=$artist?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="event" value="<?=$event?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="date" value="<?=$date?>" />

    <a id="linkAll" href="#">All</a>
</form>
```

Then use the following jQuery :

```
$('#linkAll').click( function(){
  $('#artist').val('All');
});
```

Comment: `this.form` will not work for links, as they do not have a `form` property.

Answer (score 1):

`all` is a reference to a variable that does not exist. `'all'` is a string containing the text "all".

Additionally, you assume that `this.form` exists (but it likely doesn't). You could use `parentNode` instead, but this may stop working if you move the `<a>` tag.

So:

```
<form action="index.php?explore=browse" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="artist" value="<?=$artist?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="event" value="<?=$event?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="date" value="<?=$date?>" />

    <a onclick="this.parentNode.artist.value='all'; this.parentNode.submit();return false" href="#">All</a>
```

It's usually preferred *not* to write `onclick` handlers inside HTML, instead writing *all* your Javascript elsewhere in a dedicated Javascript block/file. It keeps things nice and separated.

<sup>We also prefer `e.preventDefault` to `return false`, here, though that's a little trickier to make cross-browser so I'll leave it for another question.)</sup>

Here's an example demonstrating an overall better solution:

```
<form action="index.php?explore=browse" method="post" id="theForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="artist" value="<?=$artist?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="event" value="<?=$event?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="date" value="<?=$date?>" />

    <a href="#" id="theLink">All</a>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
var theLink = document.getElementById('theLink');
var theForm = document.getElementById('theForm');

theLink.onclick = function() {
   theForm.artist.value = 'all';
   theForm.submit();
   return false;
};
</script>
```

A version of this with the use of jQuery might look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $theLink = $('#theLink');
var $theForm = $('#theForm');
$theLink.click(function() {
   $theForm.find('[name=artist]').val('all');
   $theForm.submit();

   return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: `$theForm.artist.value='all';` would not work since `$theForm` is a jquery object. Either use  `$theForm[0].artist.value='all';` or `$theForm.find('[name=artist]').val('all');`. Or in your example `var $theForm = $('#theForm')[0];` so all the following code would work as is.